# When is a quotient group of a free group finite?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $I=\{\alpha\}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the free group $F(I)$ constructed on $\{\alpha\}$. Let $\phi_\alpha$ be the canonical homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $F(I)$. Let $r=\phi_\alpha(1)^k$ and let $N$ be the normal subgroup of $F(I)$ generated by $r$.

Let $f:F(I)\rightarrow F(I)/N$ be the canonical homomorphism and $e'$ the identity of $F(I)/N$. Write $x=f(\phi_\alpha(1))$. Then $x^k=e'$.

Why is $F(I)/N$ a finite group of order $k$? I understand that it is equal to the cyclic group $\{y\ |\ (\exists n)(n\in\mathbb{Z}\ \&\ y=x^n)\}$. I just don't get why it's finite: i.e. of order $k$?

Comment: What is this canonical homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $F(\{\alpha\})$? There are lots of homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $F(\{\alpha\})$ and unless you specify the particular universal property of $\Bbb{Z}$ that singles out a canonlcal one, they are all as good as each other (and all but 2 falsify the claim).

Comment: I am using the free product construction. Let $\text{Mo}(\{\alpha\}\times\mathbb{Z})$ be the free monoid constructed on $\{\alpha\}\times\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\phi:\text{Mo}(\{\alpha\}\times\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow F(I)$ is the canonical homomorphism. So $\phi_\alpha(x)=\phi(\alpha,x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That isn't really a canonical homomorphism: you wouldn't get such a thing from $\Bbb{Z} \to F(X)$ where $X$ has more than one element. What it is is the identification of $\Bbb{Z}$ as the free group on one generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical homomorphism $\phi_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism. Through this isomorphism the normal subgroup $N\subset F(I)$ corresponds to the normal subgroup $k\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{Z}$, an the quotient $F(I)/N$ is canonically isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/k\Bbb{Z}$.

Closer to your exposition of the problem; because $F(I)$ is generated by $\alpha$ and the canonical homomorphism $f$ is surjective, its image $F(I)/N$ is generated by $f(\alpha)=f(\phi_{\alpha}(1))$. So $F(I)/N$ is cyclic, and from $x^k=e'$ it follows that its order divides $k$ if $k\neq0$.

Moreover, if $k\neq0$ then the order is precisely $k$ because $k$ is the least positive integer such that $x^n=e'$, because it is the least positive integer such that $\phi_{\alpha}(1)^n\in N$.

On the other hand, as you already note, if $k=0$ then $N=0$ and $F(I)/N\cong F(I)\cong\Bbb{Z}$, which is *not* finite.

Comment: What if $k=0$? Must we assume $k>0$ from the get-go? Because if $k=0$, then $k\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}\simeq\mathbb{Z}$. Then $F(I)/N$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Right?

Comment: @getaf Good question; indeed if $k\neq0$ then the quotient is *not* finite, and indeed $F(I)/N\cong\Bbb{Z}$. Note that $k<0$ is also possible. I have updated my anser to include this special case.

Comment: You are right: I agree with you and the OP that the problem as stated requires $k \ neq 0$.